# FactoryGirl "create_list" not saving to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I'm seeing some weird behaviour in FactoryGirl that seems to contradict the documentation. In an Rspec test, if I do this;

```
static_groups = FactoryGirl.create_list(:static_group,5)
expect(StaticGroup.count).to eq(5)
```

The test fails (expected: 5, got: 0). If I add in explicit saves of the records;

```
static_groups = FactoryGirl.create_list(:static_group,5)
static_groups.each do |grp|
  grp.save
end
expect(StaticGroup.count).to eq(5)
```

The test passes! I thought "create" in factorygirl was supposed to do a save for you, but in this case it is plainly not saving records which can be saved straight away afterwards! Even weirder, if I interrogate the objects in the first example (where I don't do an explicit save) they all have ids, so they've definately been talking to the database!!

**EDIT**

Before anyone points out the dodgy "count" syntax, I'm using DataMapper as an ORM, that's a valid way of counting :)

Comment: Can you show the definition of `static_group` factory.

Comment: Are the database inserts being generated in the test.log?

Comment: Thank you guys for prompting me to double check the factory - found the issue *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

Ugh - nightmare.

Eventually figured out what it was - the "StaticGroup" class uses STI to figure its type out. This is a little more complex because it hooks into two databases and the class structure changed between legacy and new-world.

Long story short, I copy/pasted my group factory into the static group factory and forgot to change the type. There was a hook in the "save" method that sorts this out for me and it wasn't getting fired when factorygirl created the object.